# How to make a weighing scale with independant load cells

Tags: load-cell, wheatstone-bridge

Im working on a project for school and I need to make a scale that measures weight and also accurate pressure readings at differnt points.

Is it possible to make a scale using four independant load cells? So that I can find the pressure from each of them and then use them collectively to provide a weight reading.

Or is there any better way to make a design that measures pressure at four different points and also gives the total load weight?

where can i learn more on the subject?

Comment: All of the scales that come out of the Wun Hung Lo factory have four load cells, one in each corner.